# Using PasswordResetForm in Django

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-1.5

**My problem is:** when I submit the form it falls into the `else:` block below that I have defined in my view.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** allow a user to reset their password using the django 1.5 built in `PasswordResetForm` functionality in django auth

**Views.py**

```
def UserResetPassword(request):
    form = UserForgotPasswordForm(None, request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(from_email='admin@thedomain.com',email_template_name='mysite/reuse/forgotpassword.html', use_https=False,token_generator=default_token_generator, html_email_template_name=None)
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Are you sure you entered that correctly?")

    return render(request, 'mysite/reuse/forgotpassword.html', {
        'form':form
    })
```

**Upon submitting the form it outputs:** `Are you sure you entered that correctly?` (e.g. the value being sent from the `else:` condition

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a couple of issues:

```
def UserResetPassword(request):
    form = UserForgotPasswordForm(request.POST or None) #data=is request.POST or None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(from_email = 'admin@thedomain.com', email_template_name= 'mysite/reuse/forgotpassword.html', use_https = False, token_generator = default_token_generator, html_email_template_name=None)

    return render(request, 'mysite/reuse/forgotpassword.html', {
        'form':form
    })
```

Also, get rid of the `else` part. You want to be able to see what the error is. `render()` would show the errors.

In the forms,

```
fields = ("email")
```

should be

```
fields = ("email", )
```

Also, you should be [using `PasswordChangeForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.forms.PasswordChangeForm) if you want a form that lets a user change his/her password by entering their old password.

Comment: I'm trying to allow a user to reset their password using "Forgot Password" functionality, NOT changing it.

Comment: This is much appreciated karthikr! I'm getting an error of "[Errno 61] Connection refused" which likely means its trying to send an email (i think) but I dont have something setup?

Comment: Yeah  you might want to use console settings for email for the time being

Comment: Looks like the PasswordChangeForm link you included has expired. Here's a working one: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/forms/